# SIMCOM A7600E, can't make voice call but sms works

Tags: arduino, iot, at-command, lte, 4g

If I connect this sim module to laptop via USB, I can send and receive SMS-messages. But voice call doesn't work, it gives NO CARRIER, VOICE CALL: END

I've tried connecting the module's VCC and GND to Arduino Uno's 5v and GND in addition of USB-plug for messaging but I think these are the same power and don't provide more power because AT+CBC gives 0V.

So I assume I need to connect power from the other pins, is it the 3.7V BAT? Or is my module broken?

Comment: I was able to fix this myself. I had "preferred mode selection" set to LTE Only. It might work in some countries. By setting this to automatic with AT+CNMP=2, I was able to make calls and receive calls. I hope this helps if someone is having similar trouble.

Comment: You should convert the comment above into an (self-) answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this myself. I had "preferred mode selection" set to LTE Only. It might work in some countries. By setting this to automatic with AT+CNMP=2, I was able to make calls and receive calls. I hope this helps if someone is having similar trouble.